# How to optimize solution of nonlinear equations?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, math, assembly

I have nonlinear equations such as:

*Y = f1(X)*

*Y = f2(X)*

...

*Y = fn(X)*

In general, they don't have exact solution, therefore I use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve them. Method is iteration based and I'm looking for way to optimize calculations.
What are the ways to minimize calculation time? Avoid calculation of square roots or other math functions?
Maybe I should use assembly inside C++ code (solution is written in C++)?

Comment: Update your algorithm before resorting to ASM. Premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Please post examples for your equations.

Comment: I would say, that without telling what kind of nonlinear equation sets you have, and whether you have good starting points, you won't get very good answers to your question. There are **no** good general methods for nonlinear equations, and methods like Newton-Raphson need good starting points for them to accomplish anything substantial.

Answer (score 3):

A popular approach for nonlinear least squares problems is the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. It's kind of a blend between Gauss-Newton and a Gradient-Descent method. It combines the best of both worlds (navigates well the search space for for ill-posed problems and converges quickly). But there's lots of wiggle room in terms of the implementation. For example, if the square matrix J^T J (where J is the Jacobian matrix containing all derivatives for all equations) is sparse you could use the iterative CG algorithm to solve the equation systems quickly instead of a direct method like a Cholesky factorization of J^T J or a QR decomposition of J.

But don't just assume that some part is slow and needs to be written in assembler. Assembler is the last thing to consider. Before you go that route you should always use a profiler to check where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a number of single parameter functions to solve one at a time or a system of multi-parameter equations to solve together?

If the former, then I've often found that a finding a better initial approximation (from where the Newton-Raphson loop starts) can save more execution time than polishing the loop itself, because convergence in the loop can be slow initially but is fast later. If you know nothing about the functions then finding a decent initial approximation is hard, but it might be worth trying a few secant iterations first. You might also want to look at [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Rational Root Test in parallel. If impossible to use values of absolute precision then use closest to zero results as the best fit to continue by Newton method. 
Once single root found, you may decrease the equation grade by dividing it with monom (x-root).
Dividing and rational root test are implemented here https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/sh/omnn/math/test/Sum_test.cpp#L260

Comment: Note, you may multiply all coefficients with any value to make them real.